# jacocoTestReport task not being generated

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

```
Android Studio 3.1 Canary 8
Build #AI-173.4529993, built on January 6, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.14.14-300.fc27.x86_64
```

I am trying to use the jacoco to generate code coverage. However, when I run the command `./gradlew tasks` I don't see any tasks called `jacocoTestReport`.

I get the below error when I try and run the tasks `./gradlew jacocoTestReport`:

> Task 'jacocoTestReport' not found in root project 'EnumSample'

This is my build.gradlew file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.androidbox.enumsample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion "0.8.0"
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/build/jacoco/*.exec")

    subprojects.each {
        sourceSets it.sourceSets.main
    }

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

I have tried to clean and rebuild the project. However, the reporting task isn't there.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are searching for a wrong task to execute. By performing `./gradlew tasks` you'll be able to find **create*Flavor*CoverageReport** tasks:

[image]

After executing `./gradlew createDevDebugCoverageReport` with the setup that you have mentioned in the question I was able to find generated report at `/app/build/reports/dev/debug` directory.

Answer (score 13):

There are several things which we have to take care while using jacoco report which as follows:

**Enabled test coverage in app/build.gradle**

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**Create task for jacoco report**

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest') {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = files("${buildDir}/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec")
}
```

**Gradle command for jacoco report**

> ./gradlew clean jacocoTestReport

**Find jacoco report here**

Generated jacoco report path after successful jacocoTestReport execution.

> app/build/reports/coverage/debug/index.html

Also, I have created one android jacoco related sample repository where you can look.

https://github.com/jiteshmohite/JacocoAndroidSample

Also, please ensure you are running Gradle command inside the application directory.

Try the above-mentioned sample repository for reference. I created this with zero complexities, So everyone can go and use it.

Comment: Followed the steps but i see below in index.html
--app
No class files specified.

Answer (score 10):

There are two things:

- You need to [enable the code coverage](https://blog.gouline.net/code-coverage-on-android-with-jacoco-92ec90c9355e) support for the build type that you will be testing with. Your `build.gradle` should include the following (Which you've already included):

  ```
  android { 
      ... 
      buildTypes { 
          debug { 
              testCoverageEnabled = true 
          } 
          ... 
      } 
      ... 
  }
  ```

  - To generate a report, run `gradle testBlueDebugUnitTestCoverage` and you will see them in **“build/reports/jacoco/testBlueDebugUnitTestCoverage/”**
  - Here is a [gitHub example](https://github.com/mgouline/android-samples/tree/master/jacoco)

---

- Use [Gradle plugin](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin) that generates JaCoCo reports:

  Setup it as like this:

  ```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          mavenCentral()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.vanniktech:gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin:0.11.0'
      }
  }

  apply plugin: 'com.vanniktech.android.junit.jacoco'
  ```

---

Another solution to issue reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36994852):

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebug") { 
    group = "Reporting" 
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests." 
    reports { 
        xml.enabled = false 
        html.enabled = true 
    } 
    classDirectories = fileTree( 
            dir: './build/classes/debug', 
            excludes: ['**/R.class', 
                       '**/R$*.class', 
                       '**/*$InjectAdapter.class', 
                       '**/*$ModuleAdapter.class', 
                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.class' 
            ]) 
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs) 
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/testDebug.exec') 

    renamedFilesMap = [:] 

    // Hacky fix for issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69174. 
    // Rename files with '$$' before generating report, and then rename back after 
    doFirst { 
        new File('build/classes/debug').eachFileRecurse { file -> 
            if (file.name.contains('$$')) { 
                oldPath = file.path 
                newPath = oldPath.replace('$$', '$') 
                file.renameTo(newPath) 
                renamedFilesMap[newPath] = oldPath 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    doLast { 
        renamedFilesMap.each() { 
            newPath, oldPath -> 
                new File(newPath).renameTo(oldPath) 
        } 
    } 

}
```